# HTML5 History API initial load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

I'm trying to store the first page information when the page first loaded. So that I can retrieve back the first page information when I click on the second page.

(`Initial Page -> Page2 -> Initial Page)`

After hours of working, I decided to store a global variable called **firstLoad** and use **replaceState** instead of **pushState**. It works now.  But there is one problem, It could not go like this:

```
Initial Page -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page2
```

When **Page 3** goes back to **Page 2**, console shows:

```
GET http://localhost/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

I've Google-ed but I could not find any proper tutorial to deal with this issue, most of them suggest to use history.js, but i'm trying to learn how it works first. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var firstLoad = 1;

    $('a').on('click', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = this.href;
        var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        loadContent(path);

        if(firstLoad==1){
            console.log(firstLoad);
            console.log(currentPath);
            firstLoad=0;
            history.replaceState(currentPath, '', '');
            history.pushState({},'',path);
        }else{
            console.log('Not first load')
            history.pushState(path,'',path);
        }
    });

    //Pop State
    $(window).on('popstate', function(e){
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if(e.originalEvent && state){
            loadContent(state);
        }
    });

    //Load Content
    function loadContent(path){
        $.get(path, function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    };

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this section of code.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e){
    var state = e.originalEvent.state;
    if(e.originalEvent && state){
        loadContent(state);
    }
});
```

If we check the [MDN page on Window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate) we find that the `state` event property is the state object passed into functions such as `pushState`.

> the `popstate` event's `state` property contains a copy of the history entry's `state` object.

The means that the jQuery event object property `e.originalEvent.state` is the object you pass in on `pushState`. You could use this object for storing data, but your `loadContent` function expects a string for the URL, not an object.

I think you actually want to use `document.location` in your `popstate` handler.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e){
    loadContent(document.location);
});
```

Comment: Understood now! Thanks Alex! This issue aside, are there any better approaches for the initial page instead of declaring a global variable firstload = 1?

Comment: @DaleA.Almaraz I wouldn't think you would need to do things differently on initial load, but I'm not sure I follow what the problem is. You could post a new question, specifically about the problem.